# Accessing ports in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I want to listen/respond to localhost:9999 in Jenkins.
... with say: "Hello World"

Here is the code for the project ... includes Jenkins file etc.

https://github.com/fodon/step-two-jenkins.git

If the process were being run on a machine, I'd just connect with

```
http://localhost:9999
```

... and it responds with "Hello World"

When I do the same on a Jenkins pipeline
... it doesn't work!

I started jenkins with ...

```
docker run --rm  -u root \
-p 8080:8080 \
-p 9999:9999 \
-v jenkins-data:/var/jenkins_home \
-v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
-v "$HOME":/home  jenkinsci/blueocean
```

Now, http://localhost:8080 hosts jenkins

I start this server on CLI with :

```
> java -jar target/my-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

... it prints "Hello World" as expected.

But when I run the pipeline, I can't access the server.

What do I have to do to access the server using a Jenkins pipeline?

Comment: BlueOcean is just a user interface. Are you using this in [tag:jenkins-pipeline]? Please add your code that runs something on port 9999. I assume Jenkins is on 8080.

Comment: What's the docker image you are using? If it's self-build, what is its base image?

Comment: First, you don't need to expose 9999 in your Jenkins instance if you just want to access the port 9999 of a different application/container. 
Now the real problem is that you point to `localhost:9999` from inside you jenkins container which will resolve to the localhost of the container itself and NOT localhost of your local machine or server where your application is running on port 9999. A possible workaround but not the best solution is deploying the jenkins container in the host network.

Comment: @StephenKing yes, Jenkins is on 8080. Link to code is provided.

Comment: @Michael I think its jenkinsci/blueocean image ... complete jenkins start cmd  is included in question now.

Comment: @lvthillo I'm not sure I understand how this is structured. Based on the code provided, do you think Jenkins is running in a different container from "my-app".

Comment: @lvthillo Either way what do I have to do to access the page via my browser if the jenkins container is running on the same machine ?

Comment: So you have a local app on localhost:9999 and jenkins inside a container mapped on localhost:8080?

Comment: @lvthillo it listens on port 9999 if you see the Jetty settings. Did you try it?

Comment: This is the code where the port is set

Comment: https://github.com/fodon/step-two-jenkins/tree/master/src/main/java/com/mycompany/app look at Run.java

Comment: @StephenKing any ideas? Is anything missing?

Comment: @lvthillo did you check out the code and try? Get stuck anywhere?